# Installation error on angular full stack

Tags: angular, angular-fullstack

Hello everybody since the beginning of the week,
I try to install angular fullstack but my problem is that when I'm set up the configuration with tools I want to use in angular full stack,
I have this error message :

[image: error]

I look for this issue for 2 days.

For information I have :

```
project name : lol 
python : 2.7 
node js : 6.11 
visual studio 2015 & 2013 (for c++ components)
```

[image: info]

and before this project I installed angular and I didn't have any problem on it.

Comment: If my French is correct it is due to a file `cl.exe` that cannot be found. Maybe you need to install some tools first.

Comment: Yes but what tools ? I have already install all i need to run angular fullstack,f or me.

Comment: The tools necessary to build the native version of node-zopfli (whatever that is). CL.exe seems to be part of the Microsoft C and C++ compiler.

Comment: Ok thank's i will try this.

Comment: It's work for me, i have install c++ via visual 2015 by creating a new project in c++ and VS2015 install automatically C++ packages. Thank's to you Henry ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you solved your issue but I encountered this problem myself. I hope to provide this answer to help others who may face this ordeal.

Express server uses the **shrink-ray** module to compress assets before sending them over http. Nevertheless, **shrink-ray** depends on the **node-zopfli** module to install properly.

In order for **node-zopfli** to install properly, npm tries to download a compatible prebuilt binary. In the case of failure npm falls back to building that binary. A problem occurs occasionally when node-gyp is unable to build node-zopfli.

So, here are some paths you may explore:

1. Try installing a c++ compiler like g++ on linux. Installing **build-essentials** solved the issue for me, like installing c++ packages on windows did for you.
2. Remove the **shrink-ray** dependancy from package.json and the reference to shrink-ray in the **server/config/express.js** file.